# please explain this javascript debugger output regarding Date constructor

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, parsing, date, cross-browser

I am trying to instantiate a date so that the code works in Chrome and IE (et al). Ideally I'd like to find a simple statement rather than a UDF, if it's possible. Is it not possible to Date.parse the string value in javascript when the time chunk is represented as `T00:00:00`?

Here's what I have in the Immediate Window in Visual Studio; `caldate` contains a string representation of a date returned by the back-end database;  passing that string to `Date.parse()` returns a timestamp, `1371441600000`, and passing that timestamp to the Date() constructor returns both `Mon Jun 17 00:00:00 EDT 2013` and `[prototype]: Invalid Date`.

```
?caldate
"2013-06-17T00:00:00"
?Date.parse(caldate);
1371441600000
?new Date( Date.parse(caldate) );
Mon Jun 17 00:00:00 EDT 2013
    [prototype]: Invalid Date
```

Comment: Are you saying the above does work in Chrome, but not in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Invalid Date` is normal.  That is just what the debugger prints for the proto object of a `Date`.  I believe this is because the debugger calls the `toString` method on the proto object without supplying the actual `Date` instance, and so the `toString` method returns `"Invalid Date"`.

I suggest you read the [MDN documentation on Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

You can just use `new Date(caldate)` to create a `Date` from your string.

Comment: `new Date(caldate)` returns the 16th in Chrome and the 17th in IE. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Here is a good chart on browser compatability of date formats: http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html.  And this one too: http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/03/javascript-and-dates-what-mess.html  The string you are using should be OK for modern browsers.  The difference between the 16th and 17th you are seeing might be a difference between whether the string is being interpretted as UTC or localtime.  Maybe the links I've provided will help you sort it out.

Comment: I'll accept the answer as the explanation for the Invalid Date, and thanks for the additional charts.